# Using Sendmail from an external server

Tags: php, linux, web-applications, smtp, sendmail

I have a server with a webapp and a mail server (who use sendmail to route mails).

We need to migrate the webapp to an auto-scaling schema, so, I can't have the mail server in there, so, I'm thinking on leaving the mail server right where it is now.

So, to send mails I have different alternatives, I don't want to migrate to an external provider, the costs are to high (like 100 usd/m for mails + dedicated IP).

I'm looking for a way to connect my webapp PHP mail sending classes to this external server with sendmail.

Is there any way I can achieve this without creating my own API to send mails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows-servers you can change [SMTP](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp) in php.ini.
Also, you can try to setup relayhost through Postfix (example [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/postfix_relaying_through_another_mailserver)), but it seems like a simple API is the easiest and right solution :)

Comment: At the end we make an api :)